# ¿Cómo crear una variable se sesión con un array multidimensional?

Tags: php, formularios, post, session, get

Estoy intentando hacer un 4 en rayas para dos jugadores en PHP. Me gustaría guardar en una variable de sesión un array con la posición del tablero (fila y columna, estos valores serían fijos) y el número del jugador que por defecto estaría a 0, pero que cambiaría a 1 o 2 según el turno del jugador, en la fila y columna que elija. El problema es que en la variable de sesión no me guarda el número del jugador.

He aquí un fragmento del código:

```
session_start();

$partidas = array();
for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<8; $j++) {
        array_push($partidas,["fila" => $i, "columna" => $j, "jugador" => 0]);
    }
}

$_SESSION["partidas"] = $partidas;

$fila = "";
$columna = "";
if(isset($_GET["fila"]) && isset($_GET["columna"])){
    $fila = $_GET["fila"];
    $columna = $_GET["columna"];
}

for ($j=0; $j<count($partidas); $j++) {
    if(($partidas[$j]["fila"] == $fila) && ($partidas[$j]["columna"] == $columna)) {
        $partidas[$j]["jugador"] = $_GET["jugador"];
        $_SESSION["partidas"]["jugador[$j]"] = $_GET["jugador"];
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He removido varias líneas de código

```html
<?php
session_start();

//si la variable de sesion no existe igualarmos las partidas a un array vacio
//de lo contrario igualamos al valor de la sesion
 if(!isset($_SESSION["partidas"])){
    $partidas = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<8; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j<8; $j++) {
            array_push($partidas,["fila" => $i, "columna" => $j, "jugador" => 0]);
        }
    }
    $_SESSION["partidas"] = $partidas;

}else $partidas = $_SESSION["partidas"];


$fila = "";
$columna = "";
if(isset($_GET["fila"]) && isset($_GET["columna"])){
    $fila = $_GET["fila"];
    $columna = $_GET["columna"];
}


for ($j=0; $j<count($partidas); $j++) {


    if(($partidas[$j]["fila"] == $fila) && ($partidas[$j]["columna"] == $columna)) {
        $partidas[$j]["jugador"] = $_GET["jugador"];
        $_SESSION["partidas"] = $partidas;
    }
}

var_dump($_SESSION["partidas"]);


?>
```

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias!!